# How can I change the menu tab title? (mobile version)

Tags: magento2, menu, mobile, default, luma-theme

I use Luma theme [image]and I tried to figure out and manage it from default.xml but it didn't work. I need to change the name od tabs and add new links in tab. Where I can find it inside file?

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your default.xml file

Path :

> app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Package/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="store.menu" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Change Here</argument>
        </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: hi Suresh Chikani. any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Answer (score 0):

You have to override file into your theme,

Change  **if($label == 'Menu') $label = 'custom name'**; with your menu name.

```
magento 2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml
```

Keep below code inside above file,

```
<?php

/**
*  General template for displaying group of blocks devided into sections
*/

$group = $block->getGroupName();
$groupCss = $block->getGroupCss();
$groupBehavior = $block->getGroupBehaviour() ? $block->getGroupBehaviour() : '{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}';
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames($group, 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="sections <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="section-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-items" data-mage-init='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupBehavior ?>'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html) && ($block->getUseForce() != true)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');


                    if($label == 'Menu') $label = 'custom name';
                ?>
                <div class="section-item-title <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-title" data-role="collapsible">
                    <a class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-switch" data-toggle="switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="section-item-content <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?></div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For links you can try with your theme default.xml file,

keep below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
 <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
                <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
            </arguments>
             <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I add new links in tab? Whatever I change  in default.xml nothing's changed on the screen.

Comment: which place are you want to add links?

Comment: I have a link in one tab that I want to move to another. But I can't access to them. I found in default.xml where they should be by their id.

Comment: please show with screenshot your give your link description

Comment: I posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I want to move this in Konto tab.

and I think this is their part in .xml

```
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
                    <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.settings" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="store.settings.currency" template="currency.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
```

according to inspect element that Konto is in store.links and Service in store.settings

Comment: try with update code of xml file