# M2 - After move catalog.topnav to header.panel how to include catalog.topnav inside hamburger menu in mobile view

Tags: magento2.3.4, mobile-menu

After creating a custom theme that is inherited from a blank theme i am getting an error in mobile menu,

My mobile menu look like,

[image]

How to move all my categories into the left hide bar(toggle menu) i mean

[image]

any help thanks.

Note (web-view) - Moving element using **`<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.panel" after="logo" />`**

How to move catalog.topnav into hamburger menu in the mobile view?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain in more details

Comment: I have moved menu to after logo using  <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.panel" after="logo" /> webview okay, mobile view menu error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move `navigation.sections` instead of `catalog.topnav` and destination shoud be `header-wrapper` like below:-

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much....

Comment: Any help with custom font, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328498/57334 Thanks

Comment: Hi @Dipesh Rangani, in my tablet view my menu like web view menu, how to do in tablet view show my hamburger menu, FYI upto 767px (1 point below from tab view) showing my hamburger menu, but 7687px showing my web view menu to in tablet view any help thanks.

Comment: You can follow this : [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/mobile-menu-breakpoint-in-magento-2/150217#150217](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/mobile-menu-breakpoint-in-magento-2/150217#150217).

Comment: My dedicated post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/329170/57334