# How to set cms block design full width?

Tags: magento2.3.4, cms-block, full-width

For my design i am using cms block as my hero banner, how to set full width?

Comment: using css ???????

Comment: My cms block i gave full width, but in home page still right and left has space.

Comment: my width 100%, still its not fit on my home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add this CSS like thi :-

```
.cms-home .page-main {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Where i can add? which file?

Comment: in your block or an home page

Comment: you mean inline css right?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: can you pls help me with mobile menu https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Comment: I add a specific block, but it applied all the block in the home page, how to restrict?

Comment: you can add custom class for your block and add css for this block only

Comment: Same for commerce edition?