# Magento 2 Tablet view hamburger menu alignment issue

Tags: magento2.3.4, hamburger-menu

Up to width :767px showing hamburger menu, when it reached to 768px (Tablet view) showing web view menu, how to set with 768px showing my hamburger menu?

Note : I am using custom theme inherit from Default blank theme.

Comment: Hey did u found any solution for this?